# Meteor.call and Meteor.publish: returning Collection.find properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This is a pub I currently have:

```
Meteor.publish("searchResults", function (urlString) {
    check(urlString, String);

    Meteor.call('searchDatabase', urlString, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            return throwError(error.reason);
        }
        Session.set('searchData', result);
    });

    return [
        Posts.find({_id: {$in: Session.get('searchData')}}),
        Farmers.find({_id: {$in: Session.get('searchData')}})
    ];
});
```

I originally tried to do this:

```
Meteor.publish("searchResults", function (urlString) {
    check(urlString, String);

    Meteor.call('searchDatabase', urlString, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            return throwError(error.reason);
        }
        return [
            Posts.find({_id: {$in: Session.get('searchData')}}),
            Farmers.find({_id: {$in: Session.get('searchData')}})
        ];
    });
});
```

Turns out the latter does not return from the pub method. It just returns out of the Meteor.call function, which returns `undefined` regardless. However, the former keeps giving me a `Session is not defined` error. What am I doing wrong/What is the right way to get this done? `result` is an array that has all the `_id` of the elements in collections that I need to show.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `Session` only exists on the client FYI. That's why it's returning undefined. You can only assign session variables on the client. You also need to always show where your code is being run frpm - `server`, `client`, some common folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fuzzybabybunny mentioned, Sessions run on the client only, so the approach you're taking can't work for publications, which run on the server. The method call in the publication is an asynchronous one, so you will have to wait for its result in order to use it to return the database cursor. Try using one of the ways to use an asynchronous call in a synchronous way. Here's an example:

[Example on using npm module inside a Meteor method](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#example-on-using-npm-module-inside-a-meteor-method)

Of course there are other ways, such as the Future class in the [Fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers) package.

Comment: I just realized that if the publication is on the server, then do I even need to execute a Meteor.call? Can I just set the Meteor method as a standard function on the server-side and just call it directly in the publication? or is that not secure?

Comment: You are correct, you don't really need to call a method (unless you want to also have it exposed to the client as well). It's completely safe to have a normal function and call it directly in the publication.